# Change event trigger in backbone V1.0.0

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

i download the newest backbone V1.0.0,find some strange problem compared with V0.9.2

```
        TodosCollection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        TodosCollection.on('reset', this.addAllTodos, this);
        TodosCollection.on('change:completed', this.filterOne, this);
        TodosCollection.on("filter", this.filterAll, this);
        TodosCollection.on('all', this.render, this);
```

after add new content to collection , in V0.9.2 , only the following three sequence event trigger:

```
add
change
sync
```

but in V1.0.0 ,beside the above three

```
change:cid
"change:attributes"
"change:collection"
"change:_changing"
.....
```

so many event trigger

model

```
define([
    'lodash',
    'backbone'
], function (_, Backbone) {

    var TodoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults : {
            title : '',
            completed : false,
            order : 0
        },
        settings : {
            validation : {
                rules : {
                    title : {
                        "required" : true,
                        "min" : 5
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        toggle : function () {
            this.save({
                completed : !this.get('completed')
            });
        }
    });
    return TodoModel;
});
```

actually in model not has these triggger event ,so why this happen?

Answer (score 1):

[That](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) could be useful to know what changes between version.
Also, [that](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) too. What you mentioned are just built-in events, there's nothing wrong with them. A little bit of research/reading of Backbone's doc (pretty classic behavior when you're using Backbone) would tell you so.
If I missed a point in your question, feel free to let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot, i have checked doc, but not found the clear explanation,so post this question!

Comment: Your explanation is there: those are built-in events triggered automatically: 'change:attribute' when an attribute changed.